# Proguard and lambda expressions

Tags: java, duplicates, expression, proguard, definition

follow part of my java code:

```
Runnable task = () -> {
    if (display == null || display.isDisposed())
        return;
    display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                    updateMarketTypes();                        
        }
    });

};

return task;
```

when use proguard an error is occurred: 
note duplicate definition of library class

If i use `-dontwarn myClass` then works fine, but I would obfuscate myClass.
Thanks again.
Umberto

Answer (score 1):

Yes its good thing to mention 
-dontnote and -dontwarn in our proguard configuration file. Then only we would avoid warnings and duplicate definition information. The New version of Proguard 5.3 beta  has released two weeks before. https://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/proguard%20beta/. They told new version 5.3 could resolve obfuscate lamda expression.  I am searching the answer. I hope this small  information somebody to help and i get solution soon. Thanks.